# Don't wait for click() response in HtmlUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit

On one of the pages i parse with HtmlUnit, i need to click() a link which loads a page that is very long to load.

The thing is i don't need to wait for the response; i just have to click the link and go on doing things with my WebClient object.

```java
HtmlElement linkIdontCareAboutButHaveToClick = wc.checkAndGetElement("//div[@class='next']/a");

if (linkIdontCareAboutButHaveToClick != null)
{
    wc.click(lienValidationPropocom);
}

// do some more thing with wc without waiting
...
```

Is there a way to tell HtmlUnit to do some kind of asynchronous click() ?

Needless to say that everything has to be bound to the session.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to instantiate a new background thread to do the .click() so your main Event Dispatch Thread can continue without stopping.

First encapsulate the work to be done in the background in it's own class.
(you may have to pass your wc element in as a parameter depending on it's scope):

```java
class backgroundWork extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        wc.click(lienValidationPropocom);
    }
}
```

Then you can execute it from your main thread:

```java
if (linkIdontCareAboutButHaveToClick != null)
{
    Thread thread = new backgroundWork();
    thread.start();
}
```